# Dwarpool API Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum

I want to create a simple status website that would be hosted on a Github Page that pulled from the [Dwarfpool API](http://dwarfpool.com/api/) but i've been hitting an "Origin  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error which is blocking my GET request.

I started off using a simple $.getJSON(url, callbackFx) to make the request but as I later found I should be submitting an XMLHHttpRequest  for cross domain access which I did. Both of these methods worked while I was testing locally (running from file://) but as soon as I pushed the changes up to Github and tried to view it from online, the error I ran into the Access Control Errors. I've also tried using jsonp flags but I don't believe dwarfpool supports those because I kept getting a parse error on the response.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Sub Question: is there any security issues with having an ethereum wallet address and monitoring email address online?